# Can vim markers work with the repeat key?

Tags: vim

I regularly use the `.` key to repeat my last vim command. I'm wondering if there's a way to use it with commands performed using markers. Here's a simple example:

- Mark a line of text using `m'a`
- Move down a few lines, e.g. `5j`
- Indent the lines using `>'a` -- *indents 6 lines*
- Press `.` to repeat above command on the same 6 lines -- *will only affect 1st line*

Is there a way to get vim to apply the same marker range of the previous command when using the `.` command?

*ps. I know the above example would have been easier with `6>>`, which works with the `.`, I'm just using it as an example. I often use markers for more complex/longer commands.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the command you're repeating is `>'a`, but because of the rule "After applying the operator the cursor is mostly left at the start of the text that was operated upon" (from `:help operator`), `>'a` leaves the cursor at mark `a` if that was above your starting position. Then when you repeat `>'a` you end up with a linewise motion from that line to itself, which only re-indents one line.

Since you're left at the beginning of the block of text, to affect the same block of text again you can use the `']` (linewise) or `` `] `` (charwise) motions, which move to the *end* of the block of text just affected. So you can use `>']` to indent the same block again, and since your cursor starts and ends at the same position this time, you can repeat it additional times with `.`.

A simpler choice, though, would be to just use `V5j>` instead of `ma5j>'a`. `V` starts visual mode (linewise) at your current position, `5j` moves down 5 lines, and then `>` indents. And when you repeat using `.`, the same visual selection still pertains, so you get the desired result whether you moved up or down.

Comment: Your comment "...start of the text that was operated upon" gave me a clue. While I like your solution better than using markers, I discovered `backtick + ]` will move to the end of the previously operated text. So using `backtick + ].` will repeat the last command over the same marker range.

Comment: @somethingkindawierd that's pretty awesome and new to me. I'm going to incorporate it into my answer.